# Windows Service to continuously monitor network server on TCP port

Tags: c#, service, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

This is my first foray into socket programming. I need some help to get started. Basically, I have a server that sends out status updates on a specific TCP port. I need a client computer to look out for those update messages. I've decided to create a Windows Service in C# that will be installed on the client computer. I can't figure out if the service should be TCP listener (server) or client. Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. This comment from [TcpClient Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) threw me off:

```
// Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer
// connected to the same address as specified by the server, port
// combination.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a server that will send the updates, all you need to do to receive these updates is to create a TCP client on your host. This will serve as the listener, just connect it to the appropriate server's IP and port. Alternatively if you already have a client that connects to the server and just want to intercept the traffic, use something like tcpdump.

Comment: I have created a service that spuns a thread which pretty much listens on the connection every 10 seconds using infinite loop. I'm afraid having the thread sleep for 10 seconds, I might miss some communication. I can lower the time interval but is there a way to continuously monitor the connection without sleeping?

Comment: Not sure why you want to have a thread that sleeps and listens every 10 seconds. You can simply keep calling recv(). "If no data is available for reading, the Receive method will block until data is available." Taken from the dotnet api docs. You can simply call recv() and wait for data. Alternatively if you want to create some sort of a thread-based listening on the connection you can use whatever the alternative to unix-select is in Windows. But again I do not think there is any need of it

Comment: Javev- I already have server.receive() method implemented, didn't know it was blocking. I have "if (StopRequest.WaitOne(0))" in the worker loop to check if the service is stopped so I can close server connection and all. Is WaitOne() required as my code is already blocking?

Comment: Assuming C#'s implementation closely follows the Berkeley's socket API then no. No waiting is required. The only issue you might have depending on your implementation is when you want to kill the process if the current thread is in a blocking state.